# EAGLE - set part to a different layer without mirroring it

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad

I need to set a new layer for a part without actually mirroring it.
I have many pin headers already set up on my board and wired up, but I need some of them to face the other way (Set them to bottom layer). This is just an aesthetic feature, but it would be nice to know if I should populate it on top or on the bottom layer. I can't just mirror it, because the pins would be mismatched and would not work.

Is there some way this could be done?
Creating a new library part would be a possible solution, but with how many pin headers (and different sizes of them) there are, it would be very time consuming. (But it seems this is the only way so far)

The only thing I want is to print the outline on bottom layer of the silkscreen.

On the attached picture, I need one of them to face the other way, without changing the wiring, if possible.

Thanks.

Edit:
I only need the outline of my pin header (what is visible on the silkscreen after manufacturing) to be on the bottom layer. The routing will stay the same.

[image]

Comment: You just want the traces to be on the bottom side instead of the top? It would be useful if you could draw an "after" to go with the "before" you've already included, even if it's only regarding one or two rows. There's no way that I know of to change the schematic symbol - footprint bindings after the fact while preserving your trace routing.

Comment: Not the traces, outline of the pin header. I will edit the post to make it more clear and add a before/after screenshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I think I understand based on your comment. You want the silkscreen to move to the bottom for one of the two headers you've depicted. The easiest way to achieve that will be to make a duplicate library part, then reassign the layer of the silkcreen from tPlace to bPlace. Then in your schematic, replace the component(s) you want to be drawn on the back with your duplicate library component by right-clicking on it and choosing "Replace" and selecting it from library.

Changing the layer of the silkscreen in the library editor is most easily achieved by turning off all the layers except tPlace, then use the "Wrench" tool to select Layer => bPlace and just click on all the tPlace segments. You can speed this up a little by using the select area tool first to select the whole group at once, then click the Wrench tool, then click to apply to the whole group at once.

Comment: This. Making dupes of a library part for local customisations is cheap and easy.